# findViewById() returns null

Tags: android, android-preferences, live-wallpaper

There are a few questions already asking about this, but I'm not finding a solution. I have a LiveWallpaper that is using its own subclass of `PreferenceFragment` to specify  preferences. The solution most often cited is to assure that `setContentView()` is called before `findViewByID()`. I am not calling `setContentView()` *at all* because I do not have a layout specified. This app originally implemented the preferences using the deprecated methods like `PreferenceActivity.getPreferenceManager()` and without using a layout and worked just fine. I am trying to bring the code up-to-date in using `PreferenceFragment`.
Am I required to have a layout and if so, what would I have when I don't really want one?
Or is there a another way to get/set the View?

```
public class SetPreferenceActivity extends Activity {    
    private CheckBox redCheckBox;    

@Override  
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    //setContentView(R.layout.main);  ???
    redCheckBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.redCheckBox);  // returns null
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new LiveWallpaperPreferenceFragment()).commit();  
    }  
}
```

Comment: This is your creation code? Where do you expect to find redCheckBox, if you didn't inflate that view? You call find view on Activity, witch doesn't hold any view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create views dynamically :

```
@Override  
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText("Hello");

    setContentView(textView);//<----set the view !

    }  
}
```